# How formal should I be as a university teacher?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy

I try to be not only a good teacher but also a good friend for my students.

- I tell them that they can call me by my first name even in the formal colloquiums.
- I give them a personal phone number to call me about their math questions anytime.
- I try to spend some time each week/month for riding bicycles or watching a match with them.
- I ask about their possible personal problems and offer my help when I think there is a meaningful descending change on their grades.
- And so on.

Once one of my colleges told me:

> You pay too much attention to your students. They are just a part of your job as a university teacher. Your informal relations with students could be harmful for you and makes our job too hard because they expect all of us to treat them as like as you but we cannot respond this expectation properly and so they will think that we don't care them.

**Question.** How formal should I be as a university teacher? Can my informal behavior with my students have some disadvantages for me, my colleges, my students and my department?

Comment: What's with the down vote? This isn't Meta.

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on academia.se?

Comment: I agree with @brendansullivan07 While we had a meta-agreement that a question need not be strictly a *mathematics* eucation question, but we welcome more general question, I still feel we should not have too many very general questions. I answered myself the "kissing problem," which is just as general, and possibly this was a mistake in retrospect. Please, if you have many more such general questions, do not ask them all here, at least not at this rate.

Comment: @quid Would you please add some links to those related meta posts which you mean in your comment? It could be useful for those who read this post.

Comment: Yes, sure, here it is http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/124/pedagogical-questions-without-reference-to-mathematics An additional issue besides frequency is that this question now is not even about teaching in a narrow sense (a classroom situation like the "kissing problem") but still more general.

Comment: @quid It seems about the "rate of asking questions" we need more clarification. I will add a meta discussion post. Please explain your reasons there.

Comment: @GitGud I down-voted the post. The question is literally phrased as: "How formal should I be as a university teacher?" I find this to be far (far) too broad and not at all specific to mathematics education.

Comment: I have voted to close, and cited "too broad" as a reason and, although that does apply, I really wanted my vote to be "belongs on academia.se" (yet we can't do that yet since we're in beta).

Comment: @brendansullivan07 note that if you choose off-topic, and then 'other'  you can phrase the reason yourself. (I consider it prefereable to have a comment with the vote to close in general, so I certainly do not want to suggest doing this instead of commenting, but just in case you had not notice that possibility yet.)

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I now share your views. Thank you.

Comment: This is a good question! It is a real question that many teachers (across disciplines) face. I don't think that it is too broad. I just think that the answer is: it is culture dependent.

Comment: @quid Here is my [related meta post](http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/211/on-the-rate-of-asking-questions-in-mese) on the "frequency problem" which you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much for your support Thomas!

Comment: I thought "How formal should I be as a university teacher?" was about treating math formally, but it's about treating people formally $\ddot-$

Comment: I think, the question belongs to academic.SE.

Comment: I think if there was any possible way for the answer to have something to do with mathematics specifically, I would think the question was a good one. However, I don't think mathematics can have anything to do with it, so I've also voted to close the question.

Comment: @ChrisCunningham: You don't think that this question is relevant for mathematicians?

Comment: @Thomas no no! It's clearly relevant. However, I think that if a question is set up so that it applies to everyone in academia, then it clearly belongs more in academia.SE than ME.SE. So I voted to close for reason: it belongs in academia.SE.

Comment: I see some votes to reopen this question so I voted to reopen it too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This heavily depends on the culture that you are in. In the USA it is common for students to address their teacher by last name. If the teacher has a Ph.D., then you would call them Dr. Lastname. If the person has a military rank, then the rank overrules the academic degree. Even in the USA some schools have a tradition of being more informal.

If you are from Europe, then there might be a different culture. If you are is South Korea, then there is a different culture.

And there different cultures in different departments.

So it is impossible to answer how formal a university teacher should be with his/her students.

I think a good piece of advice (that I once got) is to ask your colleges about what they do. Go talk to your chairperson about what the standard is and the don't deviate from that. If one teacher is very formal with her students and you are very informal that might (I say might) create some conflict in a department. Students might think of the other teacher as being more strict and ask questions like "Why isn't she more like ...". You don't want that.

That said, here are some things that are worth considering when you are trying to figure out how formal/informal you want to be:

- Does being more informal with student cause a problem if you have to report the student for academic misconduct in the future?
- Does being more informal put you at risk for sexual harassment? (You really want to take this one seriously!
- Does being more informal promote learning?
- Does being more informal put me at odds with the other faculty?
- Am I so close in age to my students that I might prefer to create a distance by being very formal?
- Is my school an exclusive private school where formality is assumed?
- Are my students underprivileged and might they actually benefit from be showing an interest in their personal lived?
- Will my students take advantage of a personal relationship?

(You can probably add more to this list yourself). Again: This is all culture dependent. The answers are going to look different.

Comment: It is a really nice answer! I have a question here. Is it really necessary for a faculty member to follow the local culture of his/her university or being formal/informal in relations with students lies in the area of personal choice of each person?

Comment: @SaintGeorg: I think that it is a combination of both. You don't have to follow the culture where you are. I would ask yourself the questions that I listed above. If being "too different" will cause problems in the department, then I would hesitate, but the department might have a very diverse culture already and so you might be fine.